# Javascript, Php Handlers, CommentBox

Tags: javascript, php

```
$("#login").click(function(){

    $.getJSON("handlers/Login.php?name="+$("#username").val(), function(data){
        console.log(data);  //get whatever i have in login box and sends to my handler returning the json array
    });
        template = $("#hidebody");
    if(!data['error']){
        template.show();
        //$("#greeting")
    }
    else
    {
        template.hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

So far the top part works, which means whatever name i type in username box it is send to my handler login.php, when i do a console.log, and so on console i get my json array back from my database which works, now I need some help writing a if and else statment where the comment box appears after the person logs in, which hides the userbox, and password box, and as a greet statment displaying the person name from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Since Javascript is an asynchronous language, there's no guarantee that the data from $.getJSON will be available unless passed through a callback or returned in a promise. In my below example, I pulled the function definitions out into their own variables instead of defining them inline, to help illustrate the flow of the program.

```
// Define a login method which grabs data and passes it to a callback
var login = function (username, callback) {
    $.getJSON("handlers/Login.php?name=" + username, callback);
};

// Define a method which handles the response returned from the login URL
var handleResponse = function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    var template = $('#hidebody');

    if(!data['error']) {
        template.show();
    } else {
        template.hide();
    }
};

// Register the onClick event which calls the login method
$("#login").click(login($('#username').val(), handleResponse));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `getJSON` is going to run asynchronously you need to add your data handling functionality into that callback where you are currently logging the data.

Something like this:

```
$("#login").click(function(){

    $.getJSON("handlers/Login.php?name="+$("#username").val(), function(data){
        console.log(data);  //get whatever i have in login box and sends to my handler returning the json array
            template = $("#hidebody");
            // Any other logic for parsing / handling of returned JSON
            if(!data['error']){
                template.show();
                //$("#greeting")
            }
            else
            {
                template.hide();
            }
    });

    return false;
});
```